# Discord bot with Psycopg

Tags: python, postgresql

I've made a Discord Bot in Python that uses the Psycopg module to make calls to a PostgreSQL database in order to display information.

https://github.com/Chombler/cardbot

Specifically, I call this function when a user calls the bot:

```
def pullCardRecord(recordName):
    success = True
    try:
        print("Trying")
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user = db_credentials[0],
                                        password = db_credentials[1],
                                        host = db_credentials[2],
                                        port = db_credentials[3],
                                        database = db_credentials[4])
        print("connected")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        join_table_query = '''
        SELECT id
        FROM card
        WHERE card.name = ('%s') ''' % (recordName)

        cursor.execute(join_table_query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        print(results)
        if len(results) < 1:
            success = False
            raise ValueError('The name that was given to cardbot didn\'t exist in the card table.')

        join_table_query = '''
        SELECT  name, 
                cardclass.cardclass,
                tribe.tribe, cardtype.cardtype,
                cost, side.side, strength, trait.strengthmodifier, health, trait.healthmodifier,
                trait.trait,
                ability,
                flavor,
                cardset.cardset,
                rarity.rarity
        FROM card
        LEFT JOIN cardtoclass ON card.id = cardtoclass.cardid
        LEFT JOIN cardclass ON cardtoclass.classid = cardclass.id
        LEFT JOIN cardtotrait ON cardtotrait.cardid = card.id
        LEFT JOIN trait ON cardtotrait.traitid = trait.id
        LEFT JOIN cardtotribe ON card.id = cardtotribe.cardid
        LEFT JOIN tribe ON cardtotribe.tribeid = tribe.id
        LEFT JOIN cardtype ON cardtype.id = card.typeid
        LEFT JOIN cardset ON cardset.id = card.setid
        LEFT JOIN rarity ON card.rarityid = rarity.id
        LEFT JOIN side ON card.sideid = side.id
        WHERE card.name = ('%s') ''' % (recordName)

        cursor.execute(join_table_query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()


        print("Printing Results")
        for row in results:
            for col in row:
                print(col)
            print()

        cardInstance = cardObject(results)
        print(cardInstance.information())

        # Print PostgreSQL version
        cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You are connected to - ", record,"\n")

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
        print ("Error retrieving card information using PostgreSQL,", error)
    finally:
        #closing database connection.
        if(connection):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
        return(cardInstance.information() if success else "I'm sorry, I couldn't find a card with that name.")
```

I want to make sure that the bot is protected from any direct sql injections before I deploy it. Is it currently fairly safe or do I need to add anything to protect its integrity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unpacking

Try this rather than hard-coded indexing:

```
    user, password, host, port, database = db_credentials
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user, ...)
```

Or, if you're able to rearrange those parameters such that they match those of the [`connect` signature](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect):

> - dbname – the database name (database is a deprecated alias)
> - user – user name used to authenticate
> - password – password used to authenticate
> - host – database host address (defaults to UNIX socket if not provided)
> - port – connection port number (defaults to 5432 if not provided)

then you can simply do

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(*db_credentials)
```

### Logs

Consider replacing

```
    print("Trying")
    print("connected")
```

with calls to the actual `logging` module, which is more configurable and maintainable.

### Quote escapes

```
'The name that was given to cardbot didn\'t exist in the card table.'
```

can be

```
"The name that was given to cardbot didn't exist in the card table."
```

### In-application queries

Your `join_table_query` is long. There are several approaches to improve this - either save a view in the database (my favourite), or a stored procedure (common but I think it's overkill in this case).

### Injection

> the bot is protected from any direct sql injections before I deploy it

This is directly vulnerable:

```
'''... WHERE card.name = ('%s') ''' % (recordName)
```

Never (ever) use string formatting to insert parameters to a query. All DB connection libraries have anticipated this concern and most approach it using "prepared statements".

[This article](https://www.psycopg.org/articles/2012/10/01/prepared-statements-psycopg/) is old but relevant. The [actual reference](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) shows that you should be passing `vars` as a sequence or a mapping, which will prevent injection.